# Problems with creating a window using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a program using tkinter and it keeps on giving me this one error:

```
in __init__ self.master = TK()
NameError: name 'TK' is not defined
```

I am not sure why it is saying that TK isn't defined when I am importing tkinter, can someone please explain what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = TK()
        frame = Frame(self.master)
        frame.pack()
        self.master.minsize(1080,720)
        self.master.maxsize(1080,720)
        self.master.title("Music Player")

myapp = App()
myapp.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's `Tk`, not `TK`.

Comment: instead of writing those 578 characters in your question, you should have taken a little peek at the documentation, or paid a small heed to auto-completion of whatever IDE you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `Tk`, not `TK`. Take a look at this small code given in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program) of tkinter. The last three lines are here for you.

```
import tkinter as tk
...

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

As a matter of fact, I think you were trying the code from the documentation page, yet you missed it!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't expressing myself correctly. Essentially what I was trying to figure out was why I couldn't have the `master` within the class itself. I am new to tkinter, but I have already gone through the documentation and have programmed multiple examples myself. I am essentially wondering why I can't put the master within the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be `TK`; it should be `Tk`.